# django admin - group permissions to edit or view models

Tags: python, django

I'm searching for a way to customize the Django Administration to support permissions based on the user group.

For example, I've just created the Developers group, now I've also created the Tickets model, with AdminModel to specify how to list data.

I'd like to have this model visible only by Developers, and hidden to each other not in this group (eg filter the view based on groups).
I've read a lot of documentations, but couldn't really find and understand what to do to have it working.

For security purposes I'd also need to check user groups at runtime when adding-deleting objects for a specific model (the one I've hidden to people outside the Developers group), otherwise it would only need to know the URL to use the model :s

It looks like a simple task, but maybe I'm missing something... any 3rd party middleware, or just a way to do it? I'm also ready to edit the administration views if needed, but I need to know what do to.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ModelAdmin` has three methods dealing with user permission: `has_add_permission`, `has_change_permission` and `has_delete_permission`. All three should return boolean (`True`/`False`).

So you could do something like:

```
class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return request.user.groups.filter(name='Developers').exists()

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.groups.filter(name='Developers').exists()

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.groups.filter(name='Developers').exists()
```

When `False` is returned from one of these, it's results in a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know there was an easy admin hook for custom permissions handling!

Comment: Wow! This seems so easy to be carried out :-)
Similiar questions didn't get a so easy-to-understand solution.
Thank you so much!!

Comment: I should add to the (pretty good response) adding
<!-- language: lang-python -->

Answer (score 0):

I had tried hours to find a way to edit custom admin's（based on my custom model） permission by some click on screen，without many coding.

Use Django's /admin/auth/user/  "User permissions:part"

Finally I find this:
Just to install [django-admin-view-permission](https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-view-permission/)

and I can change the staff's custom models' permission here
[image]

Also in the group part /admin/auth/group/add/ I can create a group has certain permission, and assign specific staff to their permission group.