# Non-superuser access to Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to restrict which parts of the admin interface are visibile to which staff members - for example, one person might be responsible for only billing related items, another only for customer support, and a third might have full access.

I can provide full access by setting is_superuser to True, but I don't think I want that (I don't want all staff with access to the Admin interface to be super users).

I can allow staff members login to the Admin interface by setting is_staff to True, but once logged in the staff member doesn't have access to anything - they see "You don't have permission to edit anything'.

I tried the method described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392780/django-admin-group-permissions-to-edit-or-view-models) but I'm getting the same "You don't have permission" result:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_edit_permission(self, request):
        return True
```

Is there a way to have staff members be able to access parts of the Django admin interface without being superuser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as `has_edit_permission`. It's `has_change_permission`.

For more info on the three permission methods, see the [Django ModelAdmin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission):

> **`ModelAdmin.has_add_permission(self, request)`**
>
> > Should return `True` if adding an object is permitted, `False` otherwise.
>
> **`ModelAdmin.has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None)`**
>
> > Should return `True` if editing `obj` is permitted, `False` otherwise. If `obj` is `None`, should return `True` or `False` to indicate whether editing of objects of this type is permitted in general (e.g., `False` will be interpreted as meaning that the current user is not permitted to edit any object of this type).
>
> **`ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None)`**
>
> > Should return `True` if deleting `obj` is permitted, `False` otherwise. If `obj` is `None`, should return `True` or `False` to indicate whether deleting objects of this type is permitted in general (e.g., `False` will be interpreted as meaning that the current user is not permitted to delete any object of this type).

Comment: No idea where I got has_edit_permission from, has_change_permission works.

Answer (score 2):

For what you are wanting to do, don't override has_change_permission - just give the user(s) and/or user group(s) the corresponding permission ("Can change Xs") in addition to checking "is staff".

Comment: I tried that, did not work, possibly because I screwed up the details. I'll give it another try.